# Insert a String and a Sequential Number Every Other Column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot figure this out.

[First Few Columns of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cowo.png)

Right Now I've got a bunch of worksheets with 500-1000 columns with data. Next to each Column is a blank space I inserted. I'm Trying to insert the text "Column" Followed by a sequential number "Column1" "Column2" "Column3" etc until the data ends.

So far I have tried playing around with

```
Sub insert_column_every_other()
Dim lColumn As Long
lColumn = ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For colx = 2 To col.last Step 2
Columns(colx).Value = "Column" +1
Next
End Sub
```

but its not even close. Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you need a VBA solution?  The Excel formula solution is `=CONCATENATE("Column",COLUMN(D1) / 2 - 1)` where `D1` is the cell that it's in.

Comment: @pnuts - Good point :-D - I missed the 500-1000 columns bit and just looked at the screenshot.

Comment: @Comintern Yea unfortunately I do because there are just sooooo many columns.

Comment: @user3598756 that worked remarkabley well. It does the numbers in multiples of 2 (2,4,6,8) instead of (1,2,3,4,5) but I can probably work around that on my back end. Thank you!

Comment: @JoeHalbert, see edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub insert_column_every_other()
    Dim lColumn As Long, iColumn As Long

    With Worksheets("MySheetName") ' change "MySheetName" to your actual worksheet name
        lColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For iColumn = 2 To lColumn Step 2
            .Cells(2, iColumn).Value = "Column" & iColumn/2
        Next iColumn
    End With
End Sub
```